# When using forwardRef: WARNING in Circular dependency detected

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following Accordion component:

```
export class AccordionComponent {

  @ContentChildren(PanelComponent) panels: QueryList<PanelComponent>;

  open(panel: PanelComponent) {
    this.panels.toArray().forEach(panel => panel.active = false);
    panel.active = true;
  }  

  close(panel: PanelComponent) {
    panel.active = false;
  }    

}
```

Where PanelComponent is:

```
export class PanelComponent {

  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;

  accordion: AccordionComponent;

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AccordionComponent)) accordion: AccordionComponent) { 
    this.accordion = accordion; 
  }

  toggle() {
    if (this.active)
      this.accordion.close(this);
    else
      this.accordion.open(this);
  }

}
```

I am injecting AccordionComponent into PanelComponent so when one panel is opened I am able to close all others ...

When I compile I get the warning:

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
accordion.component.ts -> panel.component.ts -> accordion.component.ts
```

I undestand the warning but how to avoid it?

Will not this happen in many cases where forwardRef is used?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest working with `Output`s instead as this is the type of use case they're meant for. Something like this:

```
export class PanelComponent {

  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() close = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() open = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  toggle() {
    if (this.active)
      this.close.emit(this);
    else
      this.open.emit(this);
  }

}
```

Then just listen for the events on your `PanelComponent`:

```
<panel (close)="foo($event)" (open)="bar($event)"></panel>
```

Comment: But how would I close all other panels when one opens? I didn't understand how your solution solves this ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura Each component should get its unique id. Then use a service that has a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` that you call `.next()` on whenever a close/open action happens and pass the `{action: 'open/close', id: this.id}` as an argument. Then in your components you subscribe to the subject and check if the `id` parameter is equal to your component's id. If true then perform the action you also passed to the `next` call. This way you can open and close your components from anywhere by simply injecting your service and calling `.next()` on your subject.